How can I avoid downtime for AWS RDS SSL/TLS certificate rotation?
I have some production databases in RDS for which I have active connections and writes every minute. The current server certificates are expiring on 22nd August. I tried to update one, it takes 5 minutes and the database restarts. Are there any ways in which I can avoid this downtime of 5-10 minutes and still update the certificate?
